# Cannot invoke updateValue with an argument list of type (['NSObject'], forKey: String)

Tags: ios, function, swift, variables, dictionary

I created a dictionary:

```
var myDictionary = [String: [NSDate, String]]()
```

I'm trying to set values in the dictionary:

```
datesDictionary.updateValue([NSDate(), "string1"] , forKey: "string2")
```

I'm getting a compiler error:

> Cannot invoke 'updateValue' with an argument list of type
>   '([NSObject], forKey: String)'

What's wrong? What am I missing in regards to dictionaries? I didn't set it as an optional.

Comment: let employees = json["employees"]! as [[String : AnyObject]] try in this format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you do not want a array, if you know the type of every object in array and array is short.
In swift I think this is better

```
var myDictionary = [String: (NSDate, String)]()
myDictionary.updateValue((NSDate(), "string1") , forKey: "string2")
println(myDictionary)
```

Even you accept my answer, I want to point out that in your code,you act define a dictionary like this `[String : [(NSDate, String)]]`

So,your key is `String` and value is **Array**`[(NSDate, String)]`,type of every object in this Array is `(NSDate, String)`

So,if you want your code works,you have to do it like this

```
var myDic2 = [String:[NSDate,String]]()
myDic2.updateValue([(NSDate(),"string2")], forKey: "string1")
println(myDic2)
```

Comment: Do you know why in this case an array of values needs to use parentheses over the standard array brackets?